# Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "as.Date(20110505, %Y%"

Tags: r

I am not sure why I cannot do write the following code.

```
as.Date(20110505, %Y%m%d)
```

I receive the error given in the title. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be string with the `format` also in quotes

```
as.Date(as.character(20110505), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2011-05-05"
```